# How to make a mobile app using HTML CSS and JS?

Tags: java, html, css, mobile

I am planning to develop a mobile app using HTML CSS and javascript.i plan on storing data in a local file instead of a database.how can I develop this? any ideas? The app will run in the browser of the mobile device. (this eliminates login)

The concept of the project is good.ive also designed the UI.

Comment: Hi Sandaru, this question is really too broad for Stack Overflow.  You may want to check alternative discussion boards, chat systems, etc. for answers to your question.

Comment: After typing your question title into Google, it threw out a few results. Always try that first. Stack Overflow is supposed to be for developers helping each other with issues with code, not how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about making a website with a javascript app in it. Mobile apps are made with swift for IOS and android apps are made in java or c++.

There are programs that will take your website and put it inside an application container (mostly for android) but these programs are not recommended.

I would recommend learning swift or Java or c++ and make an app or using your html/css/javascript knowledge to make a web application.

Comment: You can actually build mobile apps using HTML, CSS and JS. There are tutorials on the subject, like this one --> https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mobile-frameworks/

Comment: programs like those take your website and shove it into an application container, it is not for application development and is not recommended.